# Adding two numbers inside a string

Tags: java, string, integer

This is my code:

```
String result = "10+23";
int calculatedResult = Integer.parseInt(result);
Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(calculatedResult);
```

It keeps giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cant convert `String result = "10+23";` to an int because you have a `+` there. What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to take 2 Strings and get their result, then here's the code:

```
String a = "10";
String b = "23";
int result = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);

//The sum of the two values as a String
String calculatedResult = String.valueOf(result);
Log.i("Tag", calculatedResult); //Outputs 33
```

Answer (score 0):

It give error because `"10+23"` is not a **number** it's contains a the symbol `+` and the method `Integer.parseInt(String s);` only convert strings like `"23"` or `"10.5"`
So to solve the problem try to convert etch number alone, like that

```
String number1 = "10";
String number2 = "23";
int calculatedResult = Integer.parseInt(number1)+Integer.parseInt(number2);
Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(calculatedResult);
```

for more information and examples about `Integer.parseInt(String s);` click [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm)